# serving pages from remote database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php site on a public hosting service, but the database is hosted on a private dedicated server.

I was wondering what are the dangers of serving php pages with data from a remote database and is it a good practice at all?

Comment: you can white list your db access to only for your domain .your hosting company is trusted i suppose

Answer (score 1):

1. Depends on your connection security, but it is safe enough for a basic website.
2. No, it is certainly **not** a good practice. In example, It slows down your web-site speed a lot + your site won't work, if for some reason the network connection to the remote DB is lost.